# Перевести получение файла на curl

Tags: php, curl

```
$ymlFileXml = '/var/www/html/upload/shina.xlsx';

$parameters = [
    'access-token' => '2azoMVxNgDZl12vwXGOIvalzyHvO8A7J',
    'format' => 'xlsx',
    'gzip' => true
];
$url = 'https://webmim.svrauto.ru/api/v1/catalog/unload?' . http_build_query($parameters);
file_put_contents($ymlFileXml, gzdecode(stream_get_contents(fopen($url, 'rb'))));
```

Раньше этот код выполнялся, теперь нужно для его выполнения перевести на curl, по дскажите как переписать правильно код ?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно лишь прочесть документацию по curl, [тык](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php)

Answer (score 0):

Не выкладывайте ключи вроде access-token в общий доступ ;)

Должно быть примерно так (не проверял):

```
$parameters = [
    'access-token' => 'xxx',
    'format' => 'xlsx',
    'gzip' => true
];

$url = 'https://webmim.svrauto.ru/api/v1/catalog/unload?' . http_build_query($parameters);
$fp = fopen($path, 'w');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```